# ASP.NET Identity - Reset a list of password asynchronously

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, asp.net-identity

I am trying to set/reset a large list of user passwords asynchronously in Identity 2.1.  When I run the process, it seems to get confused with the ApplicationUserManager.  (e.g. Even though I pass a new ID & password into a new thread, I get an error saying that it is trying to change the user when it has not finished the previous one.)  Since the Current Context doesn't run in a new thread, I was passing the ApplicationUserManager to the procedure doing the actual reset.  When I run it as shown (synchronously), it works fine, but it takes 2-3 second for each user.  That means running for 8-10 hours.
  If I could instantiate the ApplicationUserManager within the ProcessUser routine, I think the problem would go away, but so far I have not been able to since there is no context related to the page.
  Any fixes?

```
 Private Sub ProcessUsers()
    Dim mgr = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)() ' As New ApplicationUserManager()
    Dim ctx As New BCRContext()
    Dim ttl As Integer = 0
    Dim status As String

    ' Turn off password requirements for these temp passwords.
    mgr.PasswordValidator = New PasswordValidator() With {
        .RequireDigit = False,
        .RequireLowercase = False,
        .RequiredLength = 4,
        .RequireUppercase = False,
        .RequireNonLetterOrDigit = False
    }

    ' Get the list of user ID's and temp passswords 
    Dim qry As List(Of MyStuffDTO) = ctx.Database.SqlQuery(Of MyStuffDTO)("SELECT tmpPass.ID, Pass FROM tmpPass INNER JOIN AspNetUsers U ON U.ID=tmpPass.ID WHERE U.PasswordHash IS NULL ").ToList()

    Try

        For Each guy As MyStuffDTO In qry
            ttl += 1
            status = ttl & "/" & qry.Count & " - "

            ProcessUser(guy, mgr, status)

            'Dim task__1 = Task(Of String).Factory.StartNew(Function()
            '                                                   Return ProcessUser(guy, mgr, status)
            '                                               End Function
            '    )
        Next

        Debug.WriteLine("Done assigning tasks")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Logger.Error("Error processing guys", ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function ProcessUser(guy As MyStuffDTO, mgr As ApplicationUserManager, status As String) As String
    Dim rslt As IdentityResult = Nothing
    Dim msg As String = ""

    Try
        If mgr.HasPassword(guy.ID) Then
            rslt = mgr.RemovePassword(guy.ID)
            If Not rslt.Succeeded Then
                msg = status & "Error removing password for ID:" & guy.ID & " - " & rslt.Errors(0)
                Debug.WriteLine(msg)
                Logger.Warn(msg)
                Return msg
            End If
        End If
        rslt = mgr.AddPassword(guy.ID, guy.Pass)
        If Not rslt.Succeeded Then
            msg = status & "Error setting password for ID:" & guy.ID & " - " & rslt.Errors(0)
            Debug.WriteLine(msg)
            Logger.Warn(msg)
        Else
            msg = status & "Succeeded for ID:" & guy.ID
            Debug.WriteLine(msg)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        msg = "Error progessing guy " & guy.ID
        Logger.Error("Error progessing guy " & guy.ID, ex)
        Return msg & " - " & ex.Message
    End Try

    Return msg

End Function

Public Class MyStuffDTO
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Pass As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

My VB is a bit rough so I'll post my example in C#

After you've obtained UserManager from the OwinContext you can loop the users like this...

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id).ContinueWith((t) => { UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, t.Result, "NEW PASSWORD"); });
```

Comment: You don't need generate a token to change password. Just use `userManager.RemovePassword(userId);

userManager.AddPassword(userId, newPassword);`

Comment: Thanks for this.  The problem is I can't seem to generate a user manager from within the new thread and passing the user manager as a referenced variable crashes saying it can only do one name at a time.